# Tabbed Layout using CSS & JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I'm using a simple tab layout to present a form and it seems to work well. But I've hit an issue were I want to use two forms not one.

Tabs 1,2 & 3 are one form and tab 4 is another. When the user hits submit (only one submit button) I can use JQuery to serialise the data from form1 pass that to a php page and then serialise form2 and pass that to a php page.

The issue I have is as soon as I move the closing <\form> tag from after the 3rd tab it messes the layout..

Clicking on tab one shows `tab 1`, clicking on `tab 2` shows `tabs 2 & 4`, clicking on `tab 3` shows tab 3 and clicking on `tab 4` shows nothing..

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("ul#tabs li").click(function(e){
        if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
            var tabNum = $(this).index();
            var nthChild = tabNum+1;
            $("ul#tabs li.active").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $("ul#tab li.active").removeClass("active");
            $("ul#tab li:nth-child("+nthChild+")").addClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```

and I've created a fiddle that shows the issue

Can any one advise how I can get this to work.

Thanks

Comment: can you post html code? and where is fiddle link?

Comment: The problem will be at your design of HTML. Please show us the relevant code.

Comment: You forgot to link the fiddle you created